# How to pipe stdin in golang?

Tags: go

I'm connecting a pipe to my `stdout` in golang as follows for the purpose of testing (I stripped out the error handling codes):

```
stdout := os.Stdout
defer func() {
  os.Stdout = stdout
}()

r, w, _ = os.Pipe()
os.Stdout = w

var buf bytes.Buffer
fmt.Print(testOut)
w.Close()
io.Copy(&buf, r)
assert.Equal(t, testOut, buf.String())
```

I want to basically do something similar with `stdin` as well. Something like this:

```
stdin := os.Stdin
defer func() {
  os.Stdin = stdin
}()

r, w, _ = os.Pipe()
os.Stdin = r

var in string
w.WriteString(testIn)
// w.Close()
fmt.Scan(&in)
assert.Equal(t, testIn, in)
```

But, I cannot get this working. If I don't close `w`, `fmt.Scan(&in)` never returns. If I close `w`, I get `file already closed` error.

Any I idea how to get this working?

Comment: Try writing a newline

Comment: I have tried that like `w.WriteString(testIn + "\n")`. I didn't work.

Comment: Works for me on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ZK46IIYX12

Comment: Sorry my bad! The problem was actually that I had to use a whitespace and I was using Reader instead of Writer!